# Function f(x) approaching zero but at infinity it "explodes"

Tags: limits, analysis

Is there a ("trivial") function which approaches zero but right at infinity x, it explodes towards infinity y? I have no problem to which it might apply but I am curious if, how or how not that could exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no such thing as "right at infinity." If we're talking about real valued functions of a real variable, any argument to the function is infinitely far away from infinity.